# Netbeans PHP Validation sees endif as a syntax error

Tags: php, netbeans

I have this part of code

```
<?php for ($j=0; $j < $count; $j++): ?>
    <?php if(isset($votes[$j])): ?>
          <dt>something something</dt>
          <dd>
              <span><?php echo $result; ?>%</span>
              <div class="bar">
              </div>
          </dd>
    <?php else: ?>
          <dt>info</dt>
          <dd>
              <span>0</span>
              <div class="bar">
                  <div style="width: 0px"></div>
              </div>
          </dd>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

now Netbeans insists that on the endif line (near the end) there's a syntax error:

Error   Syntax error:
expected: exit, identifier, variable, function...

Is there some sort of known problem with the validation of endif on Netbeans ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using NetBeans 6.8. Tried your code and it doesn't have problem with `endif`, instead it said there's something wrong with `<dd>`. I believe there's mistake on 2nd line, `votes[$j]` should be `$votes[$j]`.

Comment: Could downvoter at least post a comment why did he/she give -1?

Comment: yeah I saw that error, changed it.. I think there might be an error on the HTML (this is just a piece of the code) however I don't see why it would interfere with the PHP.

Comment: well, the errors were fixed.. the bug was still there and now it's not anymore, I'm pretty sure it's a bug in the program as mentioned on my own answer

Comment: No, it's not a bug, you simply forgot to use $ there.

Comment: The thing is, I changed it and it still was just as it was.. it wasn't it I guarantee you.

Answer (score 1):

`votes` should be `$votes`

Answer (score 0):

Using `if( condition ): ... endif;` is valid, maybe it's just a case of NetBeans not being configured to see them as such, in which case it would be something to address to their support team.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php for ($j=0; $j < $count; $j++): ?>
```

should be

```
<?php for ($j=0; $j < $count; $j++){ ?>
```

and dont forget the closing tag at the end }

But the guy above me is right ;)